# What is in an Angel's knapsack?

Tags: warfare, mythical-creatures

Based shamelessly off [This Question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/90664/what-might-an-angels-knapsack-look-like)

As the Divine Host marches to war, what do they carry with them?

Despite their strong builds and capabilities of flight, they are limited to 30kg of equipment.  (Not including standard-issue Fiery Swords)

The foe awaiting them will be none other than the Legions of Hell themselves.

The road may be rough and long, but fortunately, the Angelic Physique does not require food, sleep, or mortal hygiene concerns.

With the most common logistic struggles of mortal warfare taken out of the equation, what is left for our Bringers of Divine Retribution to carry with them?

Comment: Rations. You know, Angel food cake.

Comment: The main problem you need to solve is how they can lift their bodies above the ground with their.

Comment: wings (missed a word)

Comment: They can't carry too much weight, or else they'd pierce their feet while trying to dance on the head of a pin.

Comment: Is that sword the only available weapon?

Comment: what technological level do they have?  And when you say "mortal hygiene concerns" do you mean they don't have to deal with sweat and excrement or do you mean they are self cleaning and if you throw mud at them it magically disappears?

Comment: Also are they wearing armor, uniforms, naked? They don't need food or sleep, how about water? You might just want to look at what the average soldier carries at the right technological level then just drop the stuff they don't need.

Answer (score 2):

> @Thucydides If they are wanting to argue that point they should elaborate upon it. This isn't so much an answer as an attempt at wit. I'd love for someone to argue that the messengers of god don't need such material things as weapons, rations, or armor but they'd need to explain why that is in their answer. – sphennings 2 hours ago

How to undertake this? A list of what angels do and how they do it gives us a clue:

- There are angles who lift up and strengthen the saints during times
  of trial (Matthew 4:11; Luke 22:43).
- These are also the angels who are dispatched to lead sinners to gospel workers when the sinners’ hearts are ready (Acts 10:3).
- Angelic beings can appear in our dreams to give us God’s directions (Matthew 1:20-24).
- The angels are busy in the re-gathering of Jews to Israel. Thus, the angels also help in bringing about the fulfillment of biblical prophecy (Matthew 24:31).
- Angels will accompany Christ back to earth during His second coming
  riding spirit horses (Matthew 16:27; 25:31; 2 Thessalonians 1:7-10).
- Angels are the silent witnesses to the confessions of men. (Luke
  15:8-9).
- God’s laws are given by the angels (Acts 7:53; Hebrew 2:2)
- The tree of life is guarded by angels (Genesis 3:24).
- Men’s revelations are given by the angels of God (2 Kings 1:15; Daniel
  8:19; 9:21-23; 10:10-20).
- They impart God’s will as they are obedient to Him (Acts 5:19-20; 10:1-6).

So clearly the Angels are spiritual beings, but more importantly they are charged with helping people by bringing them messages from God. The only "military" duty on the list is guarding the tree of life, and the Angel with the flaming sword who drove Adam and Eve from the Garden is probably the only one doing that job.

The helping people part is important, since the true battle between God and the Adversary is over the souls of men. Angels fight their demonic opponents not through physical combat (which would be silly, considering that they are immortal beings), but through the salvation or downfall of the souls of human beings. Angels therefore are armed with Truth and Love to assist people in finding their way to God.

Angels need no backpacks to do their work.